# How to append meta data to Web Api response

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Could you please assist on below.

1. I need to return api response as JSON response of type IEnumerable, along with the response i need to append my own json property to this return object.

   ```
   private async Task<IEnumerable<Funds>> GetFundDetails(int productid)
   {
       var action = $"productfunds/{productid}/detail";
       var res = await HttpClient.GetAsync($"{BaseResource}{action}");
       res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
       var collection = await res.Content.ReadAsAsync<Dto.FundDetail>();
       var items = (collection.Funds ?? Enumerable.Empty<Dto.Funds>()).Select<Dto.FundDetail, FundAsset>(MapFunds);
       return items;
   }
   ```

Response:

```
{
"items": [
    {
  "fundId": "036",
  "fundName": "ABC Fund",
  "amount": 1248111.26
},
{
  "fundId": "037",
  "fundName": "XYZ Fund",
  "amount": 7858564.84
}
]
}
```

Expected response:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "fundId": "036",
      "fundName": "ABC Fund",
      "amount": 1248111.26
    },
    {
      "fundId": "037",
      "fundName": "XYZ Fund",
      "amount": 7858564.84
    }
   ],
   ProductName: "PQR Product"
   ProductId: "1001"
}
```

-> I need to append ProductName and ProductId from the collection object which are the properties of Dto.FundDetail.

Comment: What problem are you encountering that prevents your proposed change?

Comment: How can I achieve expected response as shown above by appending productname and productid

Comment: Your proposed change is no longer an enumerable but a new kind of model containing some properties and an IEnumerable. One way to maintain the IEnumerable result is to add `ProductName` and `ProductId` to each of the `items`.

Comment: Or change the caller's expectations and extract the collection from the response.

Answer (score 0):

You should make new model that contains `Dto.Funds`, and `ProductId`, and `ProductName`,
somthing like this:

```
   public class NewModelToReturn{

     public List<Dto.Funds> Funds{get;set;}
     public string ProductName;
     public string ProductId;

 }
```

Btw, I also encourage you to read this mine blog post about designing ASP.NET Web Api responses to learn more about returning consistent Web Api responses (both for sucess, and failure responses): https://www.vladopandzic.com/asp-net-web-api/building-consistent-responses-asp-net-web-api/